# How to set a limit on the number of lines for methods and functions?

Tags: c++, git, jenkins

I would like to check if a (git) commit respects a certain method length limit or not.

Ideally it should check if any of the methods touched by the commit exceeds a certain threshold.

I guess a tool that integrates line counts in C++ code and git diffs may not be readily avaialble, but I'll be glad to find out that the contrary is true.

Given that such a tool does not exist, what is the most convenient way to have a list of method length, start and end line in a file?

I would exclude that using a regular expression or simple parser will work in all cases with C, C++, C++11 and possibly future versions of the language so some solution using a real parser would be preferrable.

Comment: vera++ should be able to do so.

Comment: So, if someone writes some complex code and adds about 20 lines of comments to 15 lines of actual code, that coude has to be broken up, because it's more than 30 lines? Or when you have 150 cases in a switch, you have to split the function into `if(firsthalfswich()||secondhalfswitch())` to make it past the checker for "no function longer than 100 lines"... Use humans with sense, instead of automation. If your reviewers aren't good enough, educate them on what is good code and why! [My choice of limits are arbitrary - they may not be your limits, but idea still applies]

Comment: You got it wrong. Having gerrit warn you that your code is adding 20 lines of (most probably useless) comments to a 15 lines of code or that you have a 150 cases in your switch is something that will raise awareness. Having to manually override the check once in a while will be ok, doing that every day should help you realize that your common sense may be wrong :)

Comment: (BTW: smoothed the "marketing" title to remove ambiguity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigations, the most viable option that uses a proper `C++` parser seems to be using clang via its python bindings.

First generate the `compile_commands.json` with `cmake` or in some other way

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=On
```

Then run this simple proof of concept:

```
import json
import clang.cindex
from ctypes.util import find_library

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file(find_library('clang-3.6'))
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

commands = json.load(open('compile_commands.json', 'r'))
for command in commands:
    args = command['command'].split()
    filename = command['file']
    tu = index.parse(args[-1], args[:-1])
    curs = tu.cursor
    for x in curs.walk_preorder():
        # Print only functions/methods with a source file 
        # in the home folder :)
        if x.type.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.FUNCTIONPROTO and x.location.file.name[0:5] == "/home" :
            # print only the definitions
            if x.get_definition() and x.get_definition() == x:
                print x.extent.end.line-x.extent.start.line, '\t', \
                    x.extent.start.line, '\t', \
                    x.extent.end.line, '\t', \
                    x.location.file.name, '\t', \
                    x.displayname
```

I'm still very new to the clang API, but I tried something similar (with a few more checks) on a quite big `C++` code base without a glitches.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Google Style Guide Checker](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py) on it like this:

```
cpplint.py --filter=readability/fn_size
```

That will restrict it to only checking the function size rule.

Answer (score -1):

If you use git, you could just add git hooks to check if your requirements are met.

For example:
You can add a pre commit hook if you want to check it client side,
or a pre-receive/update(called when handling a client push) hook on the server side, that rejects the push if your requirements are not met.

for more details look here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm afraid you've missed the point of the question. It's not "how to hook in git," but "what should I hook into git to get the line counts?"